# Cómo llamar el archivo de conexión en otro archivo php

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de llamar el archivo de conexión Database.php en el archivo buscar.php pero no me funciona. En las siguientes 2 imágenes se observa los archivo y la ubicación en el proyecto. Me podían dar una ayuda para llamarlo correctamente.

**Archivo Database.php**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo buscar.php**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Lo he intentado llamándolo así:**

```js
include("../../controller/Database.php");
include("../Database.php");
require_once("Database.php);
require_once("controller/Database.php);
```

Alguien me puede orientar de como es la forma correcta para **llamar el archivo Databa.php en el archivo buscar.php** teniendo en cuenta las carpetas en donde está los archivos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas, la carpeta `ajax` y la carpeta `core` están al mismo nivel, por lo que deberías llamarlo así:

```
include("../core/controller/Database.php");
```

Mediante los dos puntos (`..`) saldrías de la carpeta en la que se encuentra el archivo `Databa.php` y estarías al mismo nivel que la carpeta `core`.

Comment: iría después de: if (isset($_GET['term'])  ?

Comment: @Scorpion ¿Que contiene tu variable term? Dependerá de la lógica de tu código dónde incluyas esa línea aunque si es un archivo de conexión que supongo que será común para todas tus consultas te recomiendo que lo pongas al inicio.

Comment: El archivo de conexión es Database.php, el que se muestra en una d elas imagenes

Comment: @Scorpion Sí, me refiero. En el fichero buscar.php yo lo pondría fuera del if, al principio del fichero.

Comment: Perfecto. Y si estuviera en un archivo de la carpeta view y necesitara llamar el archivo buscar.php entonces como quedaría sabiendo que hace más saltos. @Francisco Romero.

Comment: @Scorpion Si estuviera en un archivo en la carpeta view entonces tendrías que hacer `../../controller/Database.php`

Comment: la última para terminar. En la carpeta view tengo el archivo casa.php. Necesito llamar el archivo buscar.php que esta en ajax entonces sería así: "../../ajax/buscar.php"  @Francisco  Romero

Comment: @Scorpion Tendrías que poner dos puntos más ya que si no te quedarías en la carpeta `app`